# Code does not work on android 8+ omg

Tags: java, android, android-8.1-oreo

The following code is used for sharing audios in my app, but I'm getting feedbacks from person with 8+ android, which when it's clicked to share the app date

This is where I call my sharing class.

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long l) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT);
                builder.setTitle("Olá, Marilene!");
                builder.setItems(MainActivity.this.Nomes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                isStoragePermissionGranted();
                                sendWhatsAppAudio(position);
                                return;
                            case 1:
                                propaganda();
                                return;
                            default:
                        }
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
```

This is my code for sharing an audio from my app in whatsapp

```
private void sendWhatsAppAudio(int songIndex){
        InputStream inputStream;
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
        try {
            inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(arrayAdapter.getItem(songIndex).getResId());
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), arrayAdapter.getItem(songIndex) +".mp3"));

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + arrayAdapter.getItem(songIndex) +".mp3"));
        intent.setType("audio/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Quer compartilhar onde pika de foice?"));
    }
```

error log that is displayed in the firebase console on mobile phones with android 8+

```
    android.os.FileUriExposedException: 
  at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed (StrictMode.java:2235)
  at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed (Uri.java:2348)
  at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess (ClipData.java:941)
  at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess (Intent.java:9742)
  at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess (Intent.java:9748)
  at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess (Intent.java:9727)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity (Instrumentation.java:1611)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult (Activity.java:4513)
  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult (BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult (FragmentActivity.java:67)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult (Activity.java:4471)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult (FragmentActivity.java:732)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivity (Activity.java:4832)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivity (Activity.java:4800)
  at meme.welyson.brasil.brasilmemes.MainActivity.sendWhatsAppAudio (MainActivity.java:1062)
  at meme.welyson.brasil.brasilmemes.MainActivity.access$000 (MainActivity.java:38)
  at meme.welyson.brasil.brasilmemes.MainActivity$2$1.onClick (MainActivity.java:995)
  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick (AlertController.java:1176)
  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick (AdapterView.java:318)
  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick (AbsListView.java:1188)
  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run (AbsListView.java:3157)
  at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run (AbsListView.java:4110)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:169)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6595)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: You want a search engine??

Comment: Have you checked AutoCompleteTextView?

Comment: I want a searcher to filter a listview, search for a name, and the app displays the searched items

Comment: I think the best words are you want to search data that are in listView! Which is possibly using AutoComplete TextView or you can see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html